# vertical projection with gravity as acceleration

Tags: mathematical-physics, convergence-acceleration

$\mathbf Question.$ A stone projected vertically upwards with initial speed of $u\ m/s$ rises $70\ m$ in the first $t$ seconds and another $50\ m$ in the next $t$ seconds.

$\bullet$Find the value of $u$  and $t$.

$\mathbf Attempt.$ I have tried simultaneous equation with $s=ut+.5at$ $$70=u(t)+(.5)(-9.8)(t)^2$$ $$120=u(t+1)+(.5)(-9.8)(t+1)^2$$
Since $v=u+at$I also let: $$t= \frac{-u}{-9.8}$$

In the end I got $u =49.5$and $t=5$

But that isn't the answer at all so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second equation should have $2t$ not $t+1$

Comment: In the second equarion, it should be $2t$ instead of $t+1$

Comment: i tried it and it worked!! thank you so much.